# Julia : Avoid declaring functions at the start

Tags: function, formatting, julia

I'm currently learning Julia and there's a feature that I really dislike.

Similar to how JS operates, the scripts and functions have to be declared at the start, otherwise I get an error. To demonstrate, here is the original code I had

```
final = true
while final
    val1 = SelectValue()
    val2 = SelectValue()
    oper = SelectOperation()
    makeoperation(val1, val2, oper)
    readline()
    println("Do you want to make another operation? (Y/N)")
    final = IsItOver()
end
function SelectValue()::Int64
    fin = false
    println("Enter a valid, whole numerical value")
    while !fin
        myvalue = readline()        
        if tryparse(Int64, myvalue) === nothing
            println("invalid value; entered '" * myvalue * "', expected valid Int64 value")
        else
            fin = true
            myvalue = parse(Int64, myvalue)
        end
    end
    return myvalue
end
```

which gave me an error stating that SelectValue was undeclared. The issue was fixed by shoving SelectValue at the very start of the program, as such.

```
final = true
function SelectValue()::Int64
    fin = false
    println("Enter a valid, whole numerical value")
    while !fin
        myvalue = readline()        
        if tryparse(Int64, myvalue) === nothing
            println("invalid value; entered '" * myvalue * "', expected valid Int64 value")
        else
            fin = true
            myvalue = parse(Int64, myvalue)
        end
    end
    return myvalue
end
while final
    val1 = SelectValue()
    val2 = SelectValue()
    oper = SelectOperation()
    makeoperation(val1, val2, oper)
    readline()
    println("Do you want to make another operation? (Y/N)")
    final = IsItOver()
end
```

Which is quite inconvenient, since that means the entirety of the main function has to be called at the end of the code. Nowhere in my C# and VB projects did I have to do that; as a matter of fact, it's the entire reason why one of my teachers had us use JQuery in our JS classes, just so we could declare our scripts at the start instead of at the very end.

Is there a way I can make it so my secondary functions can be declared at the end? It's all in the main anyway so I don't see why C# can do it but Julia can't, it just seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: This is not a Julia problem. This happens in any dynamic language. You can't call a function that hasn't been defined yet, regardless of whether you are using Julia, R, Python, or JavaScript. If it bothers you that much, you can separate your functions into a separate file, module, or package, and then load the necessary files/modules/packages at the beginning of your "main" script.

Comment: Note that you don't actually have a main function, you have code not in any function which is being executed before the functions are defined. If you wrote that as a `function main()` at the top, it would be fine to refer to functions defined later, so long as everything is defined before you *run* `main()`. (As mentioned, you are similarly free to put functions in any order you like within a module/package, they can all call each other.)

Comment: You can put all of your auxiliary functions (like `SelectValue`) in another file and just `include` it in the beginning. This way, visually only main code remain visible.